# Can two children with different parent have same keys in React

Tags: reactjs

Can two children with different parent have same keys in React?
For example, is it fine to have them in the same page?

```
<div key='parent1'>
  <div key='child1'></div>
  <div key='child2'></div>
</div>

<div key='parent2'>
  <div key='child1'></div>
  <div key='child2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Keys Must Only Be Unique Among Siblings](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes from my understanding this is fine.

> Keys only need to be unique between sibling elements, they don't need to be globally unique in your application. [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/react/give-sibling-elements-a-unique-key-attribute)